# My subscriber receive a message from GCP subscription with exactly 60 seconds delay sometimes

Tags: java, spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-gcp

I have an issue which happends periodically in my system, but causes major problems.

We use GCP Pub/Sub and sometimes subscriber receives a message with **exactly 1 minute delay**. In these cases only the following metrics are really spiked:

1. oldest_unacked_message_age
2. delivery_latency_health_score.expired_ack_deadlines = 0
3. expired_ack_deadlines_count

Here are the details of my subscription:
[subscription details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSHYN.png)

Notes:

1. metric unacked_messages_count isn't spiked, so the load for the system is usuall.
2. I am sure that delayed messages were sucssesfuly published in Pub/Sub and I see their correct publish_time attribute.
3. by all others metrics I can see that system isn't overloaded and subscriber is continue to pull other messages.
4. I print a log as soon as the message processing started in the subscriber, that's how I can see this delay.

We are using **google-cloud-pubsub**, **spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub**, **proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1** and **spring-integrations** client libraries to **StreamingPull** messages. We use **gRPC** protocol for this.

I assume that messages sometimes could be lost due to transient failure, but in this case they should be redelivered in 10 seconds based on my ack deadline, isn't it?
**Update:** On the messsage, which comes with 60 second delay I found an attribute `googclient_deliveryattempt=1`. As I understand it means that it is not redelivery???

I also thought that the problem could be in modifyAckDeadline requests, but I don't have any custom overriding. And as I see my client library by default use DEFAULT_MAX_ACK_EXTENSION_PERIOD = 0.
**Update:**  Hovewer, we send a StreamingPullRequest with StreamAckDeadlineSeconds = 60, because this value is initialized with STREAM_ACK_DEADLINE_DEFAULT, which is 60 in client library. But comments in StreamingPullRequest says: **"We need to set streaming ack deadline, but it's not useful since we'll modack to send receipt. Set to some big-ish value in case we modack late"**.

I expect that subscriber can receive the message immediately after it is published, or if there is a failure/lost, the message will be resend after 10-20 seconds based on my ack_deadline rather than 60 seconds.

Any advices how this could be resolved?

Comment: update:
It seems like changing StreamAckDeadlineSeconds parameter in StreamingPullRequest to 10 seconds fixed this problem.
Hovewer, I am confused between the difference in GCP subcription ackDeadline and StreamAckDeadlineSeconds of the StreamingPullRequest parameters. 
I don't understand what cases one or another Deadline is used.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring libraries use the Pub/Sub client library, which overrides the ack deadline specified in the subscription and implements its own [lease management](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/lease-management). By default, the initial ack deadline is 60 seconds, which is probably why you are seeing 60 second delays on some messages. What is likely happening is that the deadline is set to 60 seconds at the beginning and then the messages are sent out from the server, but the client restarts before the message is processed. In this scenario, the message will not be redelivered for 60 seconds.

If you want to reduce this time to 10 seconds, you need to change the maximum duration for each acknowledgment extension. When using the Java client library directly, call [`setMaxDurationperAckExtension()`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Builder#com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_Subscriber_Builder_setMaxDurationPerAckExtension_org_threeten_bp_Duration_) in the builder. If using the [Spring Subscriber Configuration](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#publishersubscriber-configuration), set `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.max-duration-per-ack-extension`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I have some questions and would be really thankful if you are able to clarify them: 

**1.** I found that default initialAckDeadline for my streeam is really set to 60 seconds. Hovewer, I see that default `maxDuraionPerAckExtenshion` and `maxAckExtenshionPeriod` are both set to 0. And in my integration test if I just sleep the subscriber thread I receive same message from the subscription in 20 seconds (10sec ackDeadline based on subscription details + 10 expBackOff). Is there a way to reproduce the delay from `StreamInitialAckDeadline` localy?

Comment: **2.** I don't see the client restarting when I have this high latency. Could this be due to network spikes or something similar?      
**3.** Based on my settings the exponential backoff is on and the minimum value is set to 10. Shouldn't the message be received after 70 seconds (60 initialStreamAck) + (10 backoff) ?      
**4.**  I found RetrySettings option - https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/gax/latest/com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings. Default values for InitialRpcTimeout is set to 60 seconds. Could this be related to my StremingPull mechanism as well?

Comment: 1. If these are set to 0 then yes, they sould not be used. That would also mean the initial ack deadline is not set as it is based on this minimum.
2. "Client restart" here could also be an internal stream restart within the library.
3. It's hard to say in great detail without knowing exactly what is going on.
4. RPC timeouts would only matter if the stream could not be established in the first place and had to be retried. Do you only see the delay when your subscribers first start up?

For this level of detailed investigation, you should enter a support ticket.

Comment: **1**. We send a StreamingPullRequest with StreamAckDeadlineSeconds = 60, because this value is initialized with STREAM_ACK_DEADLINE_DEFAULT(60),  But comments in StreamingPullRequest says: "**We need to set streaming ack deadline, but it's not useful since we'll modack to send receipt. Set to some big-ish value in case we modack late**".  **2** Sometimes it matches with stream restart, but unfortunately not always. I can see stream restarts in Subscription metrics. **4** Not only first time, I assumed that this could be because of trainsient failure. How can I enter a support ticket?

Comment: By the way, I was able to reproduce this once when I restarted my subscribers while receiving messages. But this could just be a coincidence, because I restarted them many times, but the “lucky timing” was only once. Also I was able to see that the **googclient_deliveryattempt** attribute of the delayed pubsub message is 1! But I assumed that it should be a redelivery from pubsub after 60 seconds, but since Deliveryattempt=1, it can't be a redelivery. How is it possible that pubsub doesn't resend the message within 60 seconds?

Comment: It seems like changing StreamAckDeadlineSeconds parameter in StreamingPullRequest to 10 seconds fixed this problem.
Hovewer, I am confused between the difference in GCP subcription ackDeadline and StreamAckDeadlineSeconds of the StreamingPullRequest parameters. 
I don't understand what cases one or another Deadline is used.