# Subscribers don't reconnect to the subscription when there is no traffic #2599

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-gcp

I am using StreamingPull mechanism to receive messages from the Pub/Sub.

Here is only 2 overriding for default SubscriberFactory settings:

```
@Bean
    public SubscriberFactory subscriberFactory(
            GcpProjectIdProvider id,
            TransportChannelProvider channelProvider,
            CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) throws IOException {
        PubSubConfiguration config = new PubSubConfiguration();
        config.initialize(id.getProjectId());
        config.getSubscriber().setParallelPullCount(2); //overriding1
        config.getSubscriber().setMaxDurationPerAckExtension(0); //overriding2
        DefaultSubscriberFactory factory = new DefaultSubscriberFactory(id, config);
        factory.setChannelProvider(channelProvider);
        factory.setPullEndpoint(url());
        factory.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        return factory;
    }
```

The second overriding helps me to resolve this issue: [My subscriber receive a message from GCP subscription with exactly 60 seconds delay sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711978/my-subscriber-receive-a-message-from-gcp-subscription-with-exactly-60-seconds-de)

I don't have any other overriding, but when there is no trafic I get this picute of number_of_open_streaming_pull subscription metric:
[number_of_open_streaming_pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQsL3.png)

I know that Pub/Sub prefers to avoid a long-running sticky connection and client library should reopens a StreamingPull connection. It works well when there is an active traffic. Any advice I can achive a stable reopens even when there is no traffic?

I found some issues about this:

- https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1005
  resolved as internal pub/sub issue
- https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/2552
  adviced to use Synchronous Pull, but I want to go further with Asynchronous pull because for my app lower latency and higher throughput are very important.

We are using google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub, proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 and spring-integrations client libraries to StreamingPull messages. We use gRPC protocol for this.

I expect that client library reopens connection even if there is no traffic.

Comment: How are you running your code? If your service is deployed in cloud run, there is a setting for keeping 'CPU always allocated' which when disabled results in the behaviour described in your question.  Apparently, when there is no request to the container for some time, CPU is no longer allocated to it and hence the subscriber dosen't pull messages.

Comment: There are multiple requests to my container, there is no request to PubSub only. So the server is running normally, the problem occurs when I start using pubsub.